# Python Syntax Help for Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm having issues attempting to get a bit of Python running (Python 3.4), and I was hoping someone could help me out and point out the error in my code.

I'm attempting to Screen Scrape yellow pages phone numbers from a website, but I keep getting "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" but I'm not experienced enough to find the error in my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

Company = raw_input("Enter a Company to extract the Phone Number: ")

Location = raw_input("Enter State: ")

r  = requests.get("http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=" +Company +"&geo_location_terms=" +Location)

# http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=[Company]&geo_location_terms=[Location]

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('phones.phone.primary')
```

Comment: I highly recommend using a text editor/IDE that automatically closes parens, brackets, quotes, etc. Life is too short to count parentheses - which is also why I don't use Lisp :)

Comment: Also, if you're really using Python 3.4, then your calls to `raw_input()` won't work, as it only exists in Python 2. Change it to `input()` and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added the raw_input() change to input() and its working much better. I'm using Notepad++ for my python scripting. Do you guys have any other recommended programs? I'm kind of new to programming

Comment: Personally, I use [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3), but if you're just starting out, you may benefit from some of the features found in an IDE like PyCharm. Look around, try different ones, and use what you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out a closing parenthesis on the last line of the script. It should be:

```
print(link.get('phones.phone.primary'))
```

The error message means that Python reached the end of the file ("EOF") while looking for your closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks guys. Slightly embarrassed I missed it.

Comment: @TravisGerken if this helped solve your problem, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the check mark (turning it green) next to the answer. This marks the question as having an acceptable answer, and awards [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) both for you and the answerer.

Comment: Really sorry. Didn't know I had to accept it! +accept!